# Pass Batch variable as parameter to Java class using command line

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line

How can we pass a batch variable as parameter to a Java class main method using command line? I want to pass the contents of a text file as an argument to a Java class using command line. for eg : `Java -jar TestJar.jar %BATCH_VAR%`

I have tried the below code and it doesnt seem to work :

```
echo "starting"

echo off

set keyvalue=^&Type TestDoc.txt

echo %keyvalue%  /// This is printing the right value.

pause

java -jar ErrorUpdate.jar "%keyvalue%" //// This does not pass anything to the Java class :(

pause
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you may have a misconception about what value is stored in your variable. So let me clarify exactly what is going on in your batch file.

```
set keyvalue=^&Type TestDoc.txt
echo %keyvalue%  /// This is printing the right value.
```

That is *not* printing the right value. What you have done is assigned the value `&Type TestDoc.txt` to the variable. When you then type `echo %keyvalue%`, this line gets expanded to the following line:

```
echo &Type TestDoc.txt
```

This is actually two separate commands. The first, `echo`, simply queries if the echo setting is currently on or off. The second command, `Type TestDoc.txt`, is then executed.

At no point does the variable `keyvalue` ever contain the contents of the file.

So when you have this line in your batch:

```
java -jar ErrorUpdate.jar "%keyvalue%"
```

It gets expanded to:

```
java -jar ErrorUpdate.jar "&Type TestDoc.txt"
```

This time, the `&` is enclosed in quotes, so it does not act as a statement separator, but instead is passed to your java class's main method. Your main method just sees the string `"&Type TestDoc.txt"` passed in as `args[0]`.

If you want the java application to receive the full contents of the file, you need to make your java application read the contents itself.